# Execution failed for task ':workflows-java:NodeDriver.main()

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, corda

We are trying to setup corda and run the cordapp-example on our macbook using Intellij. I am getting an error which says that the NodeDriver.main() failed but unable to debug as to what the failure is. 
This is only explanation of the error:
Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 132
I am following the setup instructions on https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/getting-set-up.html and the run instructions from https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-cordapp.html.
Gradle version: 5.4.1
JDK: 1.8.251

Comment: Isn't 132 a SEGENV..?

Comment: Can you provide more details as to which step you are facing the issue?

Comment: It looks like some issue other than a gradle problem. Could you share the full error log ?

Answer (score 2):

The error mostly comes because of the conflicting version of Java. I guess it is because a higher version of Java may be installed on your machine which the system might be defaulting to.

I suggest you should try to check and remove any conflicting Java versions or set Java 1.8 as default.